# AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'oov_token'

Tags: keras

[image]

I have this issue when I process the text. Do you know how to fix it. I just use pip install keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic Python/Pickle issue, not a Keras issue.
You can set `tokenizer.oov_token = None` to fix this.
The error was report in [github comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9099#issuecomment-358438143)